# WCF/WIF STS remember me function

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf, security

I have a asp.net website. The asp.net website connects to a wcf service. The wcf service is using a sts(security token service) with custom username/password authentication.

The asp.net page has a simple username and password login form. Now I'd like to implement a "remember me" function.

At the moment I have two solutions:

- Saving the entered user and password on the asp.net server and set a cookie with an ID.
- Saving the STS token on the asp.net server and renew it if needed.

What is the more secure solution? Do you have any other ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more secure solution is to save the token from the WCF service within your ASP.NET website, and renew if needed. The downside is that if the token expires, your users will need to re-authenticate with the WCF service. An expiring token is more secure than a static username and password as this leaves the WCF service authoritative of user sessions.

It might be worth encrypting the tokens though if you're storing them in a database.